# Assignment Branch Condition size is too high

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm making method that takes multiline string (logs) and writes new strings to array.

```
def task_2(str)
  result = []
  str.each_line do |x|
    ip = x[/^.* - -/]
    datetime = x[/[\[].*[\]]/]
    address = x[/T .* H/]
    if !ip.nil? && !datetime.nil? && !address.nil?
      result << datetime[1..-2] + ' FROM: ' + ip[0..-4] + 'TO:' + address[1..-3]
    end
  end
  result
end
```

and I need it to pass rubocop analysis with default configuration, but it gives AbcSize 18.68/15
And I'm sure that because of `if..end` statement, but how can I rewrite it?

Log example:

```
10.6.246.103 - - [23/Apr/2018:20:30:39 +0300] "POST /test/2/messages HTTP/1.1" 200 48 0.0498
10.6.246.101 - - [23/Apr/2018:20:30:42 +0300] "POST /test/2/run HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.2277
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ABC size is calculated by doing the following:

```
√(assignments² + branches² + conditionals²)
```

Let's first have a look at the assignments:

```
result = []
ip = x[/^.* - -/]
datetime = x[/[\[].*[\]]/]
address = x[/T .* H/]
```

This leaves us with 4 assignments.

Next up the branches. For this I have to mention that most of the operators are methods (thus count towards branches) for example `1 + 1` could also be written as `1.+(1)` `+` is a method on an integer. The same applies for `string[regex]`, which could be written as `string.[](regex)` `[]` is a method on strings. And `!value` which could be written as `value.!@` `!@` is a method on all objects.

With that out of the way let's count the branches.

```
str.each_line
x[/^.* - -/]
x[/[\[].*[\]]/]
x[/T .* H/]
!ip.nil? # counts for 2 (! and .nil?)
!datetime.nil? # counts for 2 (! and .nil?)
!address.nil? # counts for 2 (! and .nil?)
result << ...
datetime[1..-2]
ip[0..-4]
address[1..-3]
+ # 4 times in result << ... + ... + ....
```

This leaves us with 18 branches.

The last thing to count are the conditionals. Since Ruby uses short circuiting with the `&&` and `||` operators they will count towards conditionals.

```
if
&& # 2 times
```

This leaves us with 3 conditionals.

```
√(4² + 18² + 3²) ≈ 18.68
```

Now that we have an understanding of where the number is coming from, we can try and reduce it. The easiest way to reduce ABC size is by reducing the thing with the largest number, since this number is squared. In your case these are the branches. You already spotted where the issue lies in the question.

```
if !ip.nil? && !datetime.nil? && !address.nil?
  result << datetime[1..-2] + ' FROM: ' + ip[0..-4] + 'TO:' + address[1..-3]
end
```

Could be simplified to:

```
if ip && datetime && address
  result << "#{datetime[1..-2]} FROM: #{ip[0..-4]}TO:#{address[1..-3]}"
end
```

Taking a total of 10 branches away. 3 times `!something.nil?` (which count for 2, since `!` and `.nil?` are both counted towards branches) and 4 times `+`.

Leaving you with:

```
√(4² + 8² + 3²) ≈ 9.43
```

Comment: Wow. Very nice explanation. Mind giving me a quick run down on why.  `r = [];
  str.scan(/^([\d+\.\d+]+).*(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\]).*(?<=\s)((?:\/\w+)*?)(?=\s).*$/) { |ip, date_time, address | 
    r << "#{date_time} FROM #{ip} TO #{address}"
  };  r` is sub 3 (2.24 to be exact)

Comment: @engineersmnky You have 1 assignment `r = []`, 2 branches `str.scan`, `r << ...` and no conditionals. √(1² + 2² + 0²) ≈ 2.24

Comment: @engineersmnky You'll have to keep in mind that block parameters are not assigned by you, but by the code calling your block meaning that `ip`, `date_time` and `address` are assigned by the `scan` method. Furthermore Ruby is kinda tricky with methods, since `r << ...` look like an operator, but is actually just the method `r.<<(...)`.

Comment: I am certainly aware of what a method call is. It was more the assignment I was confused by since clearly assignment occurs at the block level albeit temporary. I just assumed that the `each_line.select` option I proposed would have the lowest result and was confused when it didn't but it makes sense now since there are 3 branches involved

Answer (score 1):

```
def task_2(str)
  result = []
  str.each_line do |x|
    ip = x[/^.* - -/]
    datetime = x[/[\[].*[\]]/]
    address = x[/T .* H/]
    if ip && datetime && address
      result << datetime[1..-2] + ' FROM: ' + ip[0..-4] + 'TO:' + address[1..-3]
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Having !variable.nil? is redundant. Basically, you are checking presence here, so #present? method would suffice, but any value that is not nil or false is considered false, so to be more idiomatic it is better to just use the form I used in the if statement. This solves ABS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use rubocop, but I did test the following with this data:

```
data = <<FILE
10.6.246.103 - - [23/Apr/2018:20:30:39 +0300] "POST /test/2/messages HTTP/1.1" 200 48 0.0498
10.6.246.101 - - [23/Apr/2018:20:30:42 +0300] "POST /test/2/run HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.2277
12.55.123.255 - - Hello
FILE
```

using `String#gsub!` and `Enumerable#select` (*Reports AbcSize of 3*)

```
def task_2(str)
  str.each_line.select do |x|
    # Without named groups 
    # x.gsub!(/\A([\d+\.\d+]+).*(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\]).*(?<=\s)((?:\/\w+)*?)(?=\s).*\z/m,
    # '\2 FROM \1 TO \3')
    x.gsub!(/\A(?<ip>[\d+\.\d+]+).*(?<=\[)(?<date_time>.*)(?=\]).*(?<=\s)(?<address>(?:\/\w+)*?)(?=\s).*\z/m,
      '\k<date_time> FROM \k<ip> TO \k<address>')
  end
end


task_2(data)
# => ["23/Apr/2018:20:30:39 +0300 FROM 10.6.246.103 TO /test/2/messages", 
#      "23/Apr/2018:20:30:42 +0300 FROM 10.6.246.101 TO /test/2/run"]
```

Here we are using `String#gsub!` with a pattern replacement, which will return `nil` if no replacement is made thus rejecting it from `Enumerable#select`.

Similar solution, although likely less efficient, using `String#match`, `Enumerable#map`, and `Array#compact` (*Reports AbcSize of 7.14*)

```
def task_2(str)
  str.each_line.map do |x|
    match = x.match(/\A(?<ip>[\d+\.\d+]+).*(?<=\[)(?<date_time>.*)(?=\]).*(?<=\s)(?<address>(?:\/\w+)*?)(?=\s)/)
    "#{match['date_time']} FROM #{match['ip']} TO #{match['address']}" if match
  end.compact
end
```

Here we are using `String#match` to extract the match data and then confirming a match and outputting the desired format if there is a match. A string that does not match will output `nil` and thus we `compact` the `Array` to remove the `nil` values.

Another option could just be to `scan` the whole `String` all at once and break out the matching groups: (*Reports AbcSize of 5*)

```
def task_2(str)
  str.scan(/^([\d+\.\d+]+).*(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\]).*(?<=\s)((?:\/\w+)*?)(?=\s).*$/)
    .map {|a| "#{a[1]} FROM #{a[0]} TO #{a[2]}"}
end
```

Can make the last one as low as *2.24* via

```
 def task_2(str)
  r = []
  str.scan(/^([\d+\.\d+]+).*(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\]).*(?<=\s)((?:\/\w+)*?)(?=\s).*$/) do |ip, date_time, address | 
    r << "#{date_time} FROM #{ip} TO #{address}"
  end
  r
end
```

Comment: Although a clean solution I can't give this a +1 since the change from the method of OP is huge and OP might not know what's going on.

Comment: @3limin4t0r very well maybe I took *"but how can I rewrite it?"* a bit too far :)

Answer (score 0):

Any time I run into a ABC too high (or similar complexity/length warnings), I'm pretty quick to just chop the method up. Your readability, testability, and maintainability almost always improve.

The quickest way is to yank out the body of a loop or conditional into a new method. Repeat as needed until you can read each method in one breath.

Similarly, if you've got big complex conditionals/loop constructs, pull that out to a new method as well.

Combining those two strategies enough times will reduce any method into roughly two method calls. That might be a bit overzealous in some cases...but it's never too far.

Here's one way you could apply that strategy to your code:

```
def task_2(str)
  result = []

  str.each_line do |x|
    ip, datetime, address = parse_line(x)

    if [ip, datetime, address].all?
      result << "#{datetime[1..-2]} FROM: #{ip[0..-4]} TO: #{address[1..-3]}"
    end
  end

  result
end

def parse_line(x)
  ip = x[/^.* - -/]
  datetime = x[/[\[].*[\]]/]
  address = x[/T .* H/]
  return [ip, datetime, address]
end

s =<<EOF
123.123.123.999 - - [2009-12-31 13:13:13] T www.google.com H"
456.456.456.999 - - [2009-12-31 13:13:13] 404"
678.678.678.999 - - [2009-12-31 13:13:13] T www.amazon.com H"
EOF

puts task_2(s)
```

Produces the output:

```
2009-12-31 13:13:13 FROM: 123.123.123.999  TO:  www.google.com
2009-12-31 13:13:13 FROM: 678.678.678.999  TO:  www.amazon.com
```

If you wanted to go even farther, you could pull the body of `each_line` out to a new method, `process_line`, etc. And if you created a class, you could avoid the messy (to my eye) multi-value returns.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem where it is conventient to use named capture groups.

```
R = /
    (?=                       # begin a positive lookahead
      (?<ip>.*\s-\s-)         # match the string in a capture group named 'ip' 
    )                         # end positive lookahead
    (?=                       # begin a positive lookahead
      .*                      # match any number of characters
      (?<datetime>[\[].*[\]]) # match the string in a capture group named 'datetime'
    )                         # end positive lookahead
    (?=                       # begin a positive lookahead
      .*                      # match any number of characters
      (?<address>T\s.*\sH)    # match the string in a capture group named 'address' 
    )                         # end positive lookahead
    /x                        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
def task_2(str)
  str.each_line.with_object([]) do |s, result|
    m = str.match(R)
    result << m[:datetime][1..-2] + ' FROM: ' + m[:ip][0..-4] +
              'TO:' + m[:address][1..-3] unless m.nil?      
  end
end
```

```
str =<<_
123.123.123.999 - - [2009-12-31 13:13:13] T www.google.com H"
456.456.456.999 - - [2009-12-31 13:13:13] 404"
678.678.678.999 - - [2009-12-31 13:13:13] T www.amazon.com
_
task_2 str
  #=> ["2009-12-31 13:13:13 FROM: 123.123.123.999 TO: www.google.com",
  #    "2009-12-31 13:13:13 FROM: 123.123.123.999 TO: www.google.com",
  #    "2009-12-31 13:13:13 FROM: 123.123.123.999 TO: www.google.com"]
```

The regular expression is conventionally written as follows.

```
R = /(?=(?<ip>\A.* - -))(?=.*(?<datetime>[\[].*[\]]))(?=.*(?<address>T .* H))/
```

Notice that where I have spaces here I had whitespace characters (`\s`) when writing the regex in free-spacing mode. That's because in free-spacing mode spaces are stripped out before the expression is evaluated. Alternatively, spaces can be preserved in free-spacing mode by enclosing them in character classes (`[ ]`).

Comment: @DavidHempy, I trust you don't mind that I used your example.

Comment: Mr. Pajama. I don't use Robocop, so could you tell me its "AbcSize" for my code?

Comment: AbcSize for task_2: 15.07